# How to access the views property for sharepoint 2013 list using DB?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Want code to access views property of SP2013 list using DB. (NOT OM or CSOM,ONLY DB)

We can do it using OM by

```
list.views
```

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft formally states [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841057/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-pr) that you should not interact with the SharePoint database directly.

> **Read operations addendum**
>
> Reading from the SharePoint databases programmatically, or manually, can cause unexpected locking within Microsoft SQL Server which can adversely affect performance.

Even if you figure out how to directly access the views property in the database, querying it that way could cause unexpected problems on your farm. Also, there's no guarantee that same query will work after a new SharePoint update.

You can, however, access the list views using SharePoint's [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245667.aspx).